# python Decimal.as_integer_ratio() output

Tags: python-3.x, decimal, fractions

Learning Decimal in the standard library, this seems to be a new function in python 3.6:

[**`as_integer_ratio()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.as_integer_ratio)
*Return a pair (n, d) of integers that represent the given Decimal instance as a fraction, in lowest terms and with a positive denominator*

So I tried it:

```
print(Decimal(1.25).as_integer_ratio())  # >>> (5, 4)
print(Decimal(1.33).as_integer_ratio())  # >>> (748723438050345, 562949953421312)
```

Works fine for `1.25`, but it is very hard to believe that `748723438050345 / 562949953421312` is the lowest term of fraction for `1.33`, maybe `133/100` could be the better output?

OK, I got answered on using `Decimal('1.33')` other than `Decimal(1.33)`, so does that mean it is preferred to input `str` other than `float` when using Decimal()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
from decimal import Decimal
print(Decimal('1.25').as_integer_ratio())  # >>> (5, 4)
print(Decimal('1.33').as_integer_ratio())

(5, 4)
(133, 100)
```

Its difference of the standard

when you do this

```
Decimal(1.25)
```

Python converts our literal base 10 representations into internal base 2 representations within the float objects. Neither of the values we have chosen can be represented exactly in base 2, so some rounding occurs. These rounded float values are then passed to the decimal constructor and used to construct the internal base 10 representations, which will be used for the computation. Finally, the operation is performed on the decimal objects. So although the decimal constructor supports conversion from float, you should always specify fractional decimal literals as strings to avoid the creation of an inexact intermediate base 2 float object

To prevent such accident please set

> To avoid inadvertently constructing decimal objects from floats, we
>   can modify the signal handling in the decimal module. We do this by
>   setting to true the value associated with the float operation key in
>   the traps attribute of the decimal module context. With this change in
>   place, our attempt to construct decimal objects directly from floats
>   raises a FloatOperation exception.

```
decimal.getcontext().traps[decimal.FloatOperation] = True
```

For example for below cases exception will be raised

```
Decimal(0.8) > 0.7
```

To answer your question

> *Decimal(1.33), so does that mean it is preferred to input str other than float when using Decimal()*

Python float type can result in problems with even the simplest of decimal values, which would be unacceptable in any application where exact arithmetic is needed such as in a financial setting. The Decimal type  is a fast correctly rounded number type for performing arithmetic in base 10. Crucially, the decimal type is still a floating point type, albeit with a base of 10 rather than 2 and has finite precision, although user configurable rather than fixed. Using decimal in place of float for say an accounting application can lead to significantly fewer hard to debug edge cases.
Decimal package was created to remove that deficiency of float.

Comment: so input with string?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the `getcontext()` setting

Comment: With `from decimal import *`, I tried `print(getcontext().traps[FloatOperation])` it returns `False`. But somehow when I `getcontext().traps[FloatOperation] = True`, it raises error?

Comment: getcontext().traps[FloatOperation] = True it will raise error for cases when you try to put  any floating value inside decimal

Comment: By default it is set to false.As a result you can use both Decimal(12.5) as well as Decimal('12.5').But once you set this flag to True getcontext().traps[FloatOperation] = True.No such human error can be performed like  if someone tries to do Decimal(0.8) > 0.7 you will get an error

Comment: I see! it is not to fix the problem, more like a notification of the problem.

Comment: yes you are right .fix is if you have selected Decimal over normal float .Do decimal operation

Answer (score 3):

You are passing in **float** objects, and it is those that introduce the imprecision, you can't represent 1 and 1/3rd in binary fractions:

```
>>> format(1.33, '.53')
'1.3300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125'
>>> (1.33).as_integer_ratio()
(748723438050345, 562949953421312)
```

Pass in a *string* instead:

```
>>> Decimal('1.33').as_integer_ratio()
(133, 100)
```

From the documentation:

> Decimal numbers can be represented exactly. In contrast, numbers like `1.1` and `2.2` do not have exact representations in binary floating point. End users typically would not expect `1.1 + 2.2` to display as `3.3000000000000003` as it does with binary floating point.

and

> If value is a `float`, the binary floating point value is losslessly converted to its exact decimal equivalent. This conversion can often require 53 or more digits of precision. For example, `Decimal(float('1.1'))` converts to `Decimal('1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625')`.

Comment: I thought the whole Decimal module is to solve the float calculation problem, if `Decimal()` takes int, floats, and strings. Shouldn't they behave the same? or at least when I input `Decimal(1.33)`, python should convert it to `Decimal('1.33)` first???

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755: they *can't* behave the same, because a `float` value is always an an approximation; the value is copied exactly.

Comment: Will you prefer to input with string than float while using Decimal then?

Comment: Absolutely. A string allows you to specify the value exactly, a float for values that can’t be presented with binary fractions is always going to be an approximation.